# How do I get an ENV variable set for rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, environment-variables, rspec-rails

I'm using foreman to start up my rails development server. It's nice that I can put all of my environment variables in the `.env` file. Is there a way to do something similar for my test environment?

I want to set an API key that I will use with the `vcr` gem, but I don't want to add the API to version control. Any suggestions besides setting the environment variable manually when I start up my tests script?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the dotenv gem --- it'll work the same as foreman and load from a .env file. (and a .env.test file for your test environments)

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: or, as an alternative, you can `RAILS_ENV=test foreman run bundle exec rspec spec`

Answer (score 45):

If you just need to set environment variables, you can either set them from command-line:

```
SOMETHING=123 SOMETHING_ELSE="this is a test" rake spec
```

Or you could define the following at the top of your `Rakefile` or `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['SOMETHING']=123
ENV['SOMETHING_ELSE']="this is a test"
```

If they don't always apply, you could use a conditional:

```
if something_needs_to_happen?
  ENV['SOMETHING']=123
  ENV['SOMETHING_ELSE']="this is a test"
end
```

If you want to use a Foreman `.env` file, which looks like:

```
SOMETHING=123
SOMETHING_ELSE="this is a test"
```

and turn it into the following and eval it:

```
ENV['SOMETHING']='123'
ENV['SOMETHING_ELSE']='this is a test'
```

You might do:

```
File.open("/path/to/.env", "r").each_line do |line|
  a = line.chomp("\n").split('=',2)
  a[1].gsub!(/^"|"$/, '') if ['\'','"'].include?(a[1][0])
  eval "ENV['#{a[0]}']='#{a[1] || ''}'"
end
```

though I don't think that would work for multi-line values.

And as @JesseWolgamott noted, it looks like you could use `gem 'dotenv-rails'`.

Comment: This answer is specially better because it offers approaches that won't rely on any specific `gem` specially when using minimalistic frameworks like `Sinatra`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One option is to alias the rspec command to be a little more specific. Put the following line in your dotfiles (`.bashrc` or `.profile` or something).

```
alias 'rspec'='RACK_ENV=test RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec'
```

Another option is to put environment variables in specific .env files:

```
# .env.test

RAILS_ENV=test
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost/test
# .. etc ..
```

Using the `dotenv` gem works or you can bring them in manually

```
$ export $(cat .env.test) && rspec
```