# Test database not using .env values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am running tests using `rails test:models` and got this error (though the tests still run)

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.
```

A database called `postgres` does not exist because I gave the DB's a different name.

My `database.yml` is :

```
# config/database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_HOST'] %>
development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB'] %>
test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_TEST_DB'] %>
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB'] %>
```

and my respective .env is :

```
# ./env
POSTGRES_USER='bob'
# If you declared a password when creating the database:
POSTGRES_HOST='localhost'
POSTGRES_DB='database1'
POSTGRES_TEST_DB='database1_test'
```

In `PSQL`, you can also see the `test` database isn't using the `.env` value for its owner but the production database is :

```
                      List of databases
     Name     |     Owner     | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |        Access privileges        
--------------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------------------
 database1      | bob          | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 database1_test | bobsurname | UTF8     | C       | C     |
```

Comment: Are those ENV variables available in the test environment?

Comment: Sorry I’m new to this - how would I check that they are? (Or make them available to TEST?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that your `ENV` variables aren't available in your test suite.

To check this try accessing them in a console:

```
> RAILS_ENV=test rails console
> ENV # should print out all your ENV variables 
> ENV['POSTGRES_TEST_DB'] # should print out the name of your test db
```

If I'm right and these `ENV` vars aren't available when your environment is `test`, you'll need to look at a strategy to include the `ENV` vars you need.

- ThoughtBot has [a few ideas](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/testing-and-environment-variables) that are pretty solid
- You can add ENV vars manually as [this SO from way back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16849716/1880203) points out

Comment: this was right (.env not being used in test) - couldn't really work out how to get it working properly so have written variables into bash instead for now

Comment: Are you using the `dotenv-rails` gem?

Comment: I was using dotenv-rails yes

Comment: Then you can ensure it's loaded on test [as suggsted](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#note-on-load-order) using `Dotenv::Railtie.load` in `application.rb`

Comment: Or just use built in "Rails credentials" feature. And get rid of `.env` files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have the database `database1_test` 
You can login to Postgres via:

1. `sudo -u postgres psql` to login into Postgres
2. `\l` will show the all database

If `database1_test` doesn't exist, run this `cmd` to create and migrate database for testing

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails db:prepare
```

Comment: hey thanks - but I checked and database1_test does exist

Comment: but it's like it's 'original' form - it doesn't have any updates from any of the migrations I've run

Comment: and the username is the default username, not the one from the .env

Comment: Did you create the database manually?

Comment: I just notice the `database1_test` belongs to `bobsurname`. I think you should try to delete the database and create it via `rails db:create`